# How to downgrade react native version after upgrading?

Tags: react-native, npm, upgrade

I was building an app on the version 0.70.6 then suddenly I saw the upgrade option after upgrading my app is not working on emulator. So, I want to downgrade the version. Please guide me.

I have tried this  npm install react-native@a.b.c . But getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

[React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) will resolve your problem.

- Left column: What's your current react-native version? => The version you want downgrade.
- Right column: To which version would you like to upgrade? => The current version you are using.

Copy content in Left column and replace your current code(Right column).